# Appending HTML elements on a loop

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom

Given a JSON structure like this one:

```
[
"Hi, ",
  {
    "tag": "a",
    "attr": {
      "href": "https://example.com",
      "target": "_blank"
    },
    "body": [
      "click ",
      {
        "tag": "strong",
        "body": [
          "here "
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "to get ",
  {
    "tag": "em",
    "body": [
      "amazing "
    ]
  },
  "offers."
]
```

I am trying to iterate over it to convert the values into HTML tags. With the above JSON I was hoping to construct this:

```
<span>Hi, </span><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">click <strong>here</strong></a>to get <em>amazing </em><span>offers.</span>
```

So I'm passing this JSON into a recursive function like so:

```
 stringHtmlText(content) {
   let result = content.map(tranche => {
        if (typeof tranche === "object") {
            let attrs = [];
            for (let attr in tranche.attr) {
                if (tranche.attr.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                    let thisAttr = {};
                    thisAttr[attr] = tranche.attr[attr];
                    attrs.push(thisAttr);
                }
            }

            return tranche.body.map(entry => {
                if (typeof entry === "object") {
                    let childNode = this.stringHtmlText([entry]);
                    if(Array.isArray(childNode)) {
                        childNode = childNode[0];
                    }
                    let parentNode = this.buildElement(tranche.tag, attrs, '');
//THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE
                    parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
                    return parentNode;
                } else {
                    return this.buildElement(tranche.tag, attrs, entry);

                }
            })[0];

        } else {
            return this.buildElement('span', [], tranche);
        }

    });
    return result;
}
```

Where buildElement is a convenience method that creates the nodes, sets attributes and appends any text nodes:

```
 buildElement(tag, attributes, value = '') {
        let node = document.createElement(tag);
        if (value) {
            let text = document.createTextNode(value);
            node.appendChild(text);
        }
        if (attributes.length === 0) {
            return node;
        }
        return this.setAttributes(node, attributes);
    }
```

The issue I am running into is that even though when debugging I see the "strong" node being passed to parentNode.appendChild(childNode), when the value is returned the parentNode "a" tag has no child "strong", giving me a result like this:

```
<span>Hi, </span><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">click </a><span>to get </span><em>amazing </em><span>offers.</span>
```

Which is obviously lacking the "strong" tag inside the "a" tag. Why is the node not being appended to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue was that the second mapping function was actually generating two nodes in the cases where there was both plain text and an additional node in the body.

Since the first iteration only contains the text node, the way to get the second, complete iteration was to pass the results of the mapping to a variable and then return the last index in the array, like so:

```
 stringHtmlText(content) {
    {
        return content.map(tranche => {
            if (typeof tranche === "object") {
                let attrs = [];
                for (let attr in tranche.attr) {
                    if (tranche.attr.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                        let thisAttr = {};
                        thisAttr[attr] = tranche.attr[attr];
                        attrs.push(thisAttr);
                    }
                }
                let parentNode;
//Assign to variable
                let trancher = tranche.body.map(entry => {
                    if (typeof entry === "object") {
                        let childNode = this.stringHtmlText([entry]);
                        if (Array.isArray(childNode)) {
                            childNode = childNode[0];
                        }
                        parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
                        return parentNode;
                    } else {
                        parentNode = this.buildElement(tranche.tag, attrs, entry);
                        return parentNode;
                    }
                });
// Return only the last, complete node

                return trancher[(trancher.length - 1)]

            } else {
                return this.buildElement('span', [], tranche);
            }

        });
    }
}
```